# Possible values of r (common ratio) if r is equal to d (common difference)

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

The common difference **d** of an AP is equal to the common ratio **r** of a GP. I have been told that the sum of the first ten terms of the AP is equal to fifteen times the sum of the first three terms of the GP.

I have tried using the formulas $\frac{10}{2}[2a+9d]$ = $15[\frac{a(1-d^3)}{1-d}]$, however I am unsure how to continue.

Comment: Have you been told the first term of the two series are the same? If not, the value to the right should have a second variable $b$ instead of $a.$

Comment: You have two equations in two unknowns.  Solve them simultaneously

Comment: It seems like one equation of $2$ unknowns, @RossMillikan and that only assuming the assumption OP made that the initial value of the AP and GP are supposed to be equal.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right, what I have written is incorrect. The first term is not equal and therefore $\frac{10}{2}[2a+9d] = 15[\frac{b(1-d^3)}{1-d}]$. Which is why I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same $d$ on both sides of your equation? Shouldn't it be $r$ on the RHS?

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani The equation that I have written is only what I have tried. However, it is not necessarily correct. I have been told however that r=d. The question ends at the end of the first paragraph of my question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need more information to get a clean answer.

If the AP starts at $a$ and the GP starts at $b,$ then the equation becomes:

$$\frac{10}{2}(2a+9d)=15b(1+d+d^2)$$

Then you get $$15bd^2+(15b-45)d+(15b-10a)=0$$

Or equivalently:

$$bd^2+(b-3)d+(b-2a/3)=0$$

This gives a quadratic formula:

$$d=\frac{(3-b)\pm\sqrt{9 - 6 b + 8 a b/3 - 3 b^2}}{2b}$$
if $b\neq 0.$

If $b=0,$ then $d=\frac{-2a}{9}.$

Given any $b$ and $d,$ we can solve:

$$a=\frac{3}2(bd^2+(b-3)d+b)$$

This shows that there are infinitely many integer trios, $a,b,d,$ specifically, when $b,d$ both even or both odd.

---

Assuming $a=b,$ you need $b^2+18b- 27\leq 0,$ or $(b+9)^2\leq 108.$ For a $b$ positive integer, there is only one value, $b=1.$ But the value of $d$ in this case is irrational, $d=1\pm 2\sqrt{2/3}.$

---

If $b=1,$ then $$d=1\pm \sqrt{2a/3}$$

So, for example, when $a=6, b=1,$ you get $d=3,-1.$ Then when $d=3$:

$$6+9+\cdots +33=195,\\1+3+3^3=13,$$ and $13\cdot 15=195.$

When $d=-1,$ $$6+5+\cdots+(-3)=15,\\1+(-1)+1=1.$$

---

If $b=3$ you want $$d=\pm\sqrt{2a/9-1}$$

You can get any odd integer $d$ from some integer $a,$ specifically, $a=\frac{9(d^2+1)}{2}.$

For $d=5,$ $a=117,$ and:

$$117+122+\cdots+162=1395=93\cdot 15,\\3+15+75=93.$$

This gives another answer for $d=3,$ with $a=45,b=3.$

$$45+48+\dots+72=585=15\cdot 39,\\3+9+27=39$$